# Node : Use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, templates

I have a node class which can store data of any type.

This is my code right now. I'm getting a error C2059: syntax error : '<' on friend class List;

```
template <typename T>
class Node{
protected:
    T info;
    Node *urm;
    Node *ant;
public:
    int get_info() { return info; }
    void set_info(T a) { info = a; }
    friend class List<T>;
};

template <typename T>
class List{
protected:
    Node<T> *p, *u;
public:
};
```

Comment: Also, don't edit the question and change the code dramatically, since the initial answers will look completely out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node` is a class template and it expects a template argument at instantiation. So you have to specify it, something like

```
Node<int> *p, *u; // Nodes of integers
    ^^^^^
    instantiate the template with int
```

Since your `Node` is a class template, I suggest making `List` a class template too, as otherwise `List` loses the ability of manipulating arbitrary types

```
template <typename T>    
class List{
protected:
    Node<T> *p, *u;
public:
};
```

**UPDATE** (but please do not change your code and question live, better ask a new one)

You should also provide a forward declaration of `List`, as otherwise it is not visible when declaring the `friend` in `Node`. In other words, put this line

```
template<typename T>
class List; // forward declaration
```

above the declaration of `Node`.

Comment: Hi! I'm getting a `'List' : class template has already been declared as a non-class template` now.

Comment: Did you also change friendship declaration?

Comment: @Shury as Maciej mentioned, use `friend class List<T>;` now

Comment: No, how should the friendship declaration be changed?

Comment: @Shury You should try finding a good C++ book and read a bit about templates. They are important and understanding how they work is fundamental. [Here is a good list.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3093378)

Comment: @Shury that's good of course, but it won't replace a good book, where you can quickly (and correctly) learn the fundamentals.

Comment: @Shury see the updated edit, you need to provide a forward declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
template<typename T>
class List{
    protected:
    Node<T> *p, *u;
    public:
};
```

You need to provide a template argument list to `Node` to create its objects.